# Ionic Vue PWA - 404 error when reloading the page

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, http-status-code-404, progressive-web-apps

My team and I have created an Ionic application in Vue. We turned this application into a PWA and we have the following problem: When you reload the page from the browser, in any path, it throws 404 error.

One solution would be to redirect every path(/*) in the server to the default path. But we would like a more simple solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Apache , the solution is to create an .htaccess file in the root of your site:

1. Enable .httaccess files. In the end of  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf (name of the file might differ), add the following code:

```
 ServerName localhost 
 ServerAdmin dimdimopoulos@outlook.com 
 DocumentRoot /**projects_folder_name**/
 <Directory /**projects_folder_name**/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

2. Create the .htaccess in the root of your site, with the following code :

```
 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /**your_site_root_folder**/ [L]
```

I hope this helps.

Best regards